# createMaterialTopTabNavigator backgroundColor not defaulting to theme primary color

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, styling

I am trying to use my theme primary color for the background of my createMaterialTopTabNavigator, but it is not defaulting to the theme color, and I can't access the theme outside of a component.

Basically I am using React-Native-Paper's default theme right now and it looks something like this (This purple color is the color I want):

[image]

Now the MaterialTopBarNavigator looks like this (It's not using the theme's default purple color):
[image]

So basically, I am trying to find a way to access my theme outside of a component so I can pass it into the style object in createMaterialTopTabNavigator tabBarOptions

My index.js looks like this

```
const myDarkTheme = {
  ...DarkTheme,
  headerDark: true
};

const myDefaultTheme = {
  ...DefaultTheme,
  headerDark: true
};

export const ThemeContext = React.createContext(null);

export default class Main extends Component {
  state = {
    theme: myDefaultTheme
  };

  _toggleTheme = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        theme: prevState.theme.dark ? myDefaultTheme : myDarkTheme
      };
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <ThemeContext.Provider
        value={{ theme: this.state.theme, toggleTheme: this._toggleTheme }}
      >
        <PaperProvider theme={this.state.theme}>
          <App />
        </PaperProvider>
      </ThemeContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => Main);
```

Here is my createMaterialTopTabNavigator

```
const AccountNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
  {
    Profile: { screen: Profile },
    Preferences: { screen: Preferences }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Profile",
    swipeEnabled: true,
    animationEnabled: true,
    tabBarOptions: {
      labelStyle: { fontWeight: "bold" },
      //I would add this here to change background color
      //but I don't know how to access my theme color from here...
      //style: { backgroundColor: insertThemePrimaryColorHere }
    }
  }
);
```